# Get data response on WSO2

Tags: wso2, response

I have received an message response in WSO2 from Endpoint when i send the data. Im newbie in WSO2. Can you show me how to get the value of Job tag (00000559) on message?

Below is received message.

Thanks & Regards,

```
 [2013-08-24 13:25:08,295]  INFO - LogMediator To: , WSAction: http://www.abc.com/ns/transaction/Post, SOAPAction: http://www.abc.com/ns/transaction/Post,
    MessageID: urn:uuid:1e939de3-3ade-4aea-afdf-9e1defcae760, Direction: response, Envelope: <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http:/
    /schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><soap:Body><PostResponse
     xmlns="http://www.syspro.com/ns/transaction/"><PostResult>&lt;?xml version="1.0" encoding="Windows-1252"?>
    &lt;postjob Language='05' Language2='EN' CssStyle='' DecFormat='1' DateFormat='01' Role='01' Version='6.1.058' OperatorPrimaryRole='   '>
    &lt;Item>
    &lt;Job>00000559&lt;/Job>
    &lt;ItemNumber>         1&lt;/ItemNumber>
    &lt;/Item>
    &lt;StatusOfItems>
    &lt;ItemsProcessed>1&lt;/ItemsProcessed>
    &lt;ItemsInvalid>0&lt;/ItemsInvalid>
    &lt;/StatusOfItems>
    &lt;/postjob>
     </PostResult></PostResponse></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use XPATH expressions to get the value of any tag.

If you need to log the value in job tag, use below in the out sequence

```
<log>
        <property name="VM_LOG" expression="//PostResponse//PostResult//postjob//Item/Job"/>
     </log>
```

If you need to send it as the response, you can simply use the payload factory mediator inside the out sequence

```
     <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
        <format>
           <results xmlns="">$1</results>
        </format>
        <args>
           <arg evaluator="xml" expression="//PostResponse//PostResult//postjob//Item/Job"/>
        </args>
     </payloadFactory>
```

Finally you can add the send mediator.

```
<send/>
```

Thanks.